# Does iOS have an API for accessing smart cards

Tags: ios, smartcard, pki

I see that it is possible to connect smart card readers to an iPad or iPhone. 
Does iOS have an API for accessing smart cards - or does it require proprietary SDK’s from the smart card reader manufactures?
Specifically I want to use the certificate stored on the smart card to sign a message.

Comment: The readers you attach to a device are going to have their own API as they are 3rd party devices.

What reader you using?

Comment: We are developing software for iOS and are considering supporting smart cards as part of our solution (because of user requests). So we are not using any particular reader. We were hoping for an iOS API (but couldn't find any) to handle this in a general way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, require proprietary SDK..

For example you can easily use:

- UniMag, Mobile MagStripe Reader "..reader that works with various mobile devices.., ...Plugs into audio headphone jack – no cables..."

The SDK is there... in page... http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/112.html

- another reader with own SDK: http://www.magtek.com/support/software/programming_tools/